# Sharepoint mobile compatibility

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a existing sharepoint site. 
How can I make this site mobile compatible . DO I need to create separate pages for mobile view and navigate to them when ever user browses the site in mobile? And could any you refer any useful links for the above

Any help is appriciated

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, sharepoint is already capable of handling mobile view.

[image]

Here you can see that it is already indicated in the site information regarding the mobile site for the sharepoint site. You can access this through site actions>site settings and you will see it on the right portion of the screen.

Comment: How does the mobile redirection takes place ... I mean in mobile view we won't be displaying complete data as in desktop view .. Do we need to create separate pages for mobile view n desktop view and direct accordingly or sharepoint 2010 itself will do it ?

Comment: if you wouldn't use all the data shown in the desktop view, then i think you need to create a separate page for this that would only be for the mobile view.

Comment: thanks kee for the reply ... after creating separate pages for desktop and mobile view .. how can we redirect to those pages accordingly